# Prove De Morgan's Laws (Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Statement: Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $R$.  Show that $(A \cup B)'=A'\cap B'$.

My attempt: To show that two sets are equal to one another we have to show that $(A \cup B)' \subset A'\cap B'$ and $  A'\cap B'\subset (A \cup B)'$.  Beginning with the former, suppose that $x \in (A \cup B)'$ then $x\notin A \cup B$. This implies that $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$, which in turn should imply that $x\in A'$ or $x\in B'$. However the author of my textbook states that: $$x\notin A \text{ or } x\notin B \Rightarrow x\in A' \text{ and } x\in B'$$ Whereas, I think that the following should be true: 
$$x\notin A \text{ or } x\notin B \Rightarrow x\in A' \text{ or } x\in B'$$

Why did the **or** change into an **and**?

Comment: Alright, I got it. I guess I was just cconfused about the words...Please right this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: If the refrigerator is not in the apartment composed of kitchen and bathroom it means that you cannot find it neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NO** : $x∉A∪B$ means that $x∉A$ **and** $x∉B$.

To be element of the [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Union_of_two_sets) of two sets means to belong at least to one of them.

Thus, if $x$ does **not** belong to the union of $A$ and $B$, it means that $x$ cannot be element neither of $A$ nor of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$(A \cup B)'$ can be written as $\neg [(x \in A) \vee (x \in B)] \implies \neg (x \in A) \wedge  \neg(x \in B) = A' \cap B'$

Comment: This is wrong... you are using the DeMorgan laws to prove them... Its circular.

Comment: @Masacroso It is not intended to be a proof. He asked "Why did the **or** change into an **and**?". I thought it would be easier to see why that might be the case if it was expressed in this way.