# Proving De-Morgan laws for sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Prove that $(A \cap B) ' = A' \cup B' $

Let $ x \in (A \cap B) '$. So $ x \notin (A \cap B) $. So $x \in A-B$ or $x \in B-A$. So $x \in A'$ or $x \in B'$. So $x \in A' \cup B' $.

Let $x \in A' \cup B'$.

Case 1 : $x \in  A'$. So $x \notin A$ so $x \in B-A$
Case 2 : similarly $x \in A-B$

So $x \in (A-B) \cup (B-A)$ and so $x\notin A \cap B$

Is this correct ?

Comment: somethings wrong with the first step

Comment: when you`re proving these things it would be better if you keep doing thieir venn diagrams alongside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your proof.  We cannot assume from $x \notin (A\cap B)'$ that either $x \in A-B \lor x\in B-A$, because $x$ may not be in either $A$ nor $B$.  This cannot be the case if $x \in A-B$ or $x \in B-A$, because this implies $x$ is in one of A or B, and we don't know that.

Consider, e.g., $x \notin A \land x \notin B$.  Then $x \in (A\cap B)',$ but $x \notin A-B,$ nor is $x \in B-A$.

In fact, $A\triangle B = A-B \lor B-A$, is the symmetric difference of A, B, which can also be defined, $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)'$.

Here I use element chasing, and DeMorgan's Law in propositional logic, to prove (one of) DeMorgan's laws for sets.  Note that set union correlates with the inclusive form of or.

$$\begin{align} x\in (A\cap B)' &\iff x \notin (A\cap B)\\ \\ & \iff \lnot (x \in (A\cap B)) \\ \\ & \iff \lnot (x \in A \land x\in B) \\ \\ &\iff \lnot(x \in A) \lor \lnot(x \in B)\\ \\ & \iff x \in A' \lor x\in B'\\ \\ & \iff x\in A'\cup B'\end{align}$$

Comment: You are using De morgan law to prove De morgan law

Comment: I'm using DeMorgan's Law in logic, which can be proven via deduction, in logic, to prove the law.  In terms of sets, DeMorgan's Law can be proven based on DeMorgan's in logic.

Comment: Is there other way to do this ?

Comment: You saw no problem in using logic to justify "So x∈A′ or x∈B′. So x∈A′∪B′."

Comment: I do not understand the difference

Comment: [See this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946188/prove-de-morgans-laws-set-theory?rq=1), for the discussion on the other DeMorgan's law **for sets**.

Comment: The first answer would be equivalent to me saying, here:  If $x$ is not in $A\cap B$, then that means $x$ is not in A, or it is not in B, because it is not in $A\cap B$.  I did the same, a bit more formally, explicitly using DeMorgan's Law (logic).